# How to join a consul client to consul server running in docker container through Node.js Consul client?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, consul

I am new to Consul.

I have a [consul docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul) running in server mode as a part of the docker-compose environment. I have various microservices running in the same environment which need to be registered with Consul.

My Approach :

1. Register the service with Consul Agent local to the microservice through Node.js [Consul client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul#agent-service-register)
2. Join the consul client to the consul server running in docker-compose

How do I execute step 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [retry_join](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/deployment-guide#datacenter-auto-join) option as either a parameter to the CLI command or in the agent config file?  That's how you tell a consul client where to go to join the mesh.